# How do I add rubocop-rails and rubocop-rspec to config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubocop, rubocop-rspec

```
> bundle exec rubocop
```

```
The following RuboCop extension libraries are installed but not loaded in config:
  * rubocop-rails
  * rubocop-rspec
```

Where do I add these?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following to the top of your `.rubocop.yml` file

```yaml
require:
  - rubocop-rails
  - rubocop-rspec
```